# Javascript: Discount applied once to shopping cart

Tags: javascript

I have this discount calculation working:

```
// DISCOUNT FUNCTIONALITY
function discountCart() {
    var discount = 20
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

    if (cartCost >= 50) {
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost - discount)
        console.log('discount', cartCost - discount)
    }
};
```

Now, when a user deletes items from their cart or removes them the discount is not removed so then there is a negative balance.  What can I do to prevent this from happening?

```
function deleteButtons() {
    let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.product ion-icon');
    let productName;
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
    var discount = 20
    


    for(let i=0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
        deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            productName = deleteButtons[i].parentElement.textContent.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');
            // console.log(productName);
            // console.log(cartItems[productName].name + " " + cartItems[productName].inCart)
            localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers - cartItems[productName].inCart );

            localStorage.setItem('totalCost', cartCost - ( cartItems[productName].price * cartItems[productName].inCart) - discount);
            console.log(discount)
            delete cartItems[productName];
            localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));

            displayCart();
            onLoadCartNumbers();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what i would suggest is not to calculate individual discount update on delete rather re-calculate the total cart items after removing the deleted item, Since that way you can ensure nothing is going wrong, else this could become error prone with more code.

Comment: I would suggest keeping an array of product IDs and quantities instead, then calculating the price/discounts when it's needed. Storing prices locally (even if this is a learning exercise) is going to cause you unnecessary issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's look at some problems in your implementation.

```js
// DISCOUNT FUNCTIONALITY
function discountCart() {
    var discount = 20
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

    if (cartCost >= 50) {
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost - discount)
        console.log('discount', cartCost - discount)
    }
};
```

---

```js
var discount = 20
```

The first problem is that the coupon is hardcoded, rather than being dynamic. This makes it a lot harder to change the value and extending the options.

---

```js
// getting
let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

// setting
localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost - discount)
```

The second problem is that you are storing the total cost in local storage. You only want to store objects and arrays in local storage, as you can just read once, after page load, and have all your stored data imported.

---

```js
function deleteButtons() {
    let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.product ion-icon');
    let productName;
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
    var discount = 20
```

Here again you can see that you are retrieving the values from the local storage again.

---

Now let's clean the code up, and fix the problems.

First, we will make a basket object that will store our items and coupons.

```js
const basket = {
  items: [{
    name: "charger",
    price: 12
    amount: 1,
  }, {
    name: "pizza",
    price: 15,
    amount: 2,
  }, {
    name: "mirror",
    price: 25
    amount: 1,
  }],
  coupons: [{
    discount: 15,
    type: "gt",
    target: 50,
  }],
}
```

Now we can access the data easily through the basket object.

We can now easily store and retrieve all our data using local storage too.

```js
// getting
const basket = localStorage("basket");

// setting
localStorage("basket", basket);
```

Now let's clean up the delete buttons function.

```js
function deleteButtons(){
    const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.product ion-icon');

    deleteButtons.forEach(elm => elm.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // filtering out the deleted item;
        basket.items = basket.items.filter((item) => item.name == elm.parentElement.name);
        // deleting the parent element from the DOM.
        elm.parentElement.remove();
    }));
}
```

Now, with less code, we have added functionality to the delete buttons.

Note that some parts are guessed since you haven't given any HTML.

We could also update the basket in the local storage when deleting, but I haven't just for simplicities’ sake.

---

Now for the discount function, we will make a few things first.

```
interface Coupon {
    discount: number;
    type: string;
    target: any;
}
```

This is a modal of our Coupon object.
Discount is how much gets removed from the price.
Type is the comparison type we want to do.
Target is what we want to compare against.

The reason why we need these last two properties is, so we can dynamically apply coupons.

If we want to check that they have spend at least $50, then the object would look like this:

```js
{
    discount: 15,
    type: "le", // larger than or equal to
    target: 50,
}
```

So from looking at the object, we can tell what check to do.

---

To do the check, we will use a map/object. This is just to make our code simpler and faster.

```js
const couponCheck = {
  ge: (price, coupon) => {
    return price >= coupon.target ?
      price - coupon.discount :
      price;
  },
}
```

Now we can pass check the coupon by running:

```js
couponCheck[coupon.type](totalPrice, coupon);
```

This is a lot easier and cleaner than using for loops, or a switch statement.

Now we can add all the code we have written so far.

```js
const basket = {
  items: [{
    name: "charger",
    price: 12
    amount: 1,
  }, {
    name: "pizza",
    price: 15,
    amount: 2,
  }, {
    name: "mirror",
    price: 25
    amount: 1,
  }],
  coupons: [{
    discount: 15,
    type: "ge",
    target: 50,
  }],
}

function deleteButtons() {
  const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.product ion-icon');

  deleteButtons.forEach(elm => elm.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // filtering out the deleted item;
    basket.items = basket.items.filter((item) => item.name == elm.parentElement.name);
    // deleting the parent element from the DOM.
    elm.parentElement.remove();
  }));
}

const couponCheck = {
  ge: (price, coupon) => {
    return price >= coupon.target ?
      price - coupon.discount :
      price;
  },
}

function getTotal() {
  let itemsPrice = basket.items.map(item => item.price)
    .reduce((total, price) => total + price);
  for (coupon of basket.coupons) {
    itemsPrice = couponCheck[coupon.type](itemsPrice, coupon);
  }
  return itemsPrice;
}

console.log(getTotal());
```

If you need any further help, or clarification, just ask.